# Execute a file in multiple folders

Tags: batch-file, cmd, powershell-cmdlet

I need a command BACH to allow me to run a file to multiple folders . This executable file is already copied these folders.

```
for /D %i in (C:\Teste\*) do Paint.bat %i
```

The above command did so, however , he runs paint.bat contained in the folder " test " FOR the other subfolders , not what 's right .

Subfolders already contains a copy of paint.bat . I need a command to execute each of these copies . It's the same file , however , it needs to be run within each folder .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not switch the work folder, your code calls the Bat-file from one place always. Try this

```
for /D %i in (C:\Teste\*) do pushd .&cd "%i"&call Paint.bat %i&popd
```

Now I cannot check this, but I think it works so:

- remember current folder in stack (pushd .)
- switch current folder to the value of %i
- execute Paint.Bat (it must be placed in each subfolder)
- restore current folder from stack (popd)

This script is not recursive, only subfolders will be walked. 
Excuse my English.

Comment: Excelente...but...

How can I prevent it performs the function for folders which have been executed ?



If I create a new folder within the ' test ' their function is performed again in all folders . I wish it were only performed on each new folder added in ' Test '

Comment: The simplest way is delete script (add del /Q Paint.bat after CALL). Then the call of it will be failed.

Answer (score 0):

Erm...
Am i right with:

```
FOR /D %I IN ("Anyfolder\*") DO
```

: %I will be the Fullqualified Path to each subfolder in "Anyfolder" (not any deeper). 
You want to execute the file "paint.bat" which is located in each folder - 
and paint.bat should be startet with the fullqualified path to that folder it's in?

So isn't it just:

```
FOR /D %I IN ("Anyfolder\*") DO "%~I\paint.bat" "%~I"
```

?
Maybe you must specify a Start before:

```
FOR /D %I IN ("Anyfolder\*") DO START "" "%~I\paint.bat" "%~I"
```

(Start sometimes makes trouble when not doublequoting - or setting - a windowtitle.)